# Recreate strlcat function, got killed by a Segmentation fault (Signal -11)

Tags: c

I have an exercise for school where I need to recreate the `strlcat` function.

I understand that the function takes "src" and copies it at the end of "dest" depending on "size".

If "size" is bigger than the size of "dest", it copies "src" to "size" - 1 and put "\0" at the end.  It should return the size of "dest" + and what the copy of "src" - the place for "\0".

If "size" is smaller than "dest", it should do nothing to size and return the size total of "dest" + "src".

I got a segmentation fault when it was tested by the school programme.  I don't know what is wrong in my code. I try it with a lot of cases but got the same thing as the original function.

If I could got your help it will be more than appreciated.

```
unsigned int ft_strlcat(char *dest, char *src, unsigned int size)
{
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int b;

    i = 0;
    b = 0;
    while (dest[i])
        i++;
    while (src[b])
        b++;
    b = i + b;
    while (src != '\0' && i < size)
    {
        dest[i] = *src;
        src++;
        i++;
    }
    i--;
    dest[i] = '\0';
    return (b);
}


int main()
{
    char a[10]="1234";
    char b[10] ="123";
    char c[10] = "1234"; 
    char d[10] ="123";

    printf("strlcat=%lu %s\n",strlcat(a,b,4),a);
    printf("ft=%u %s\n",ft_strlcat(c,d,4),c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you run this with your debugger?

Comment: You first need to dereference your `src` pointer: `while (*src != '\0' && i < size)`, also trigger the warnings when compiling and treat them as errors.

Comment: ^^^^ that error mentioned by @ooj-001 means whatever test cases you're using, they're not thorough enough. The loop case to break on the *first* condition has never been thoroughly exhausted.

Comment: Segmentation Fault: you're trying to `dest[-1] = '\0';` ... *there are other problems with your code*

Comment: yeah i put a if in it for ,"if(i < size)" it should not do the dest[-1] = "\0" and just return (b);

Comment: `while (src != '\0'` is invalid. You are comparing pointer value with an integer. Also `i--; dest[i] = '\0';` is invalid. When `size = 0`dest = ""`, then `i=0`, then `i--` makes it `i=-1` or `i = UINT_MAX`. It will access dest outside or range.

Comment: yeah , i should put *src , thanks kamil , i put a if for when size is 0 so it should just return (b) the total size of the src+dest

Comment: what do you mean by dereference src ? @WhozCraig

Comment: Um.. I never said a *thing* about dereferencing `src`. ooj-001 and Kamil did, and both are spot-on accurate.

Comment: Ops sorry @whozcraig , I tired :D , yeah it was ooj-001

Comment: You are comparing a pointer `src` and and character constant `'\0'`. What you want is comparing the value pointed at by `src` not the pointer itself. To do this you dereference the pointer to get the value: `*src != \'0'` will then be valid.

Comment: thanks you @ooj-001 i make the change and will summit it again ;D

Comment: Also please [have a look](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/lib/string.c#L329) on how it has been written in `string.h`, it seems simpler than what you are trying to do.

Comment: the retun was bad but i undestand what was wrong , if we put nothing as a src , it will go in the copy fonction without copy anything and put a "\0" at i-- ,but "i" is 0 in a unsigned int so it should not work , i put a conditions to avoid this , and will summit it later , thanks everyone